# swift conditional function return

Tags: ios, function, swift, return, conditional-statements

I would like to know how to manage conditional returns in swift. For instance, I'm returning a custom UICollectionViewCell depending on which collectionview delegate is called:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1)) {
         var cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
         return cell
      }
      else if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2)) {
        var cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
        return cell
      }
}
```

The compiler says "Missing return statement in a function expeted to return UICollectionViewCell", even in both cases I'm returning a cell.

I solved it adding

```
return UICollectionViewCell()
```

at the bottom of the function, but I don't think it's the correct way.

I know I can declare the cell above the first 'if', modify it and return it at the end of the function outside the 'if', but then the 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' call hangs.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To explain @MidhunMP's answer, right now your code is able to end without any return value. For example look at this code, which is similar to yours:

```
func myFunc() -> Int {
    let myNumber = random() % 3
    if myNumber == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    else if myNumber == 1 {
        return 1
    }
}
```

What if `myNumber` is 2? The function ends without any return value, and this cannot happen.

Either move the return statement to the end of the code, or add an `else` clause. Both ensure that your function will return a value under all circumstances.

You will need either:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
    if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1)){
        cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
    } else if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2)){
        cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
    }
    return cell
}
```

or,

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
    if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1)){
        cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
    return cell
    } else if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2)){
        cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
    return cell
    } else {
        return cell;
    }
}
```

However, use the first one because it is more elegant and it is easier to understand its meaning.

Comment: Your answer has give me the key. If I replace the "else if" by an "else" it works perfectly.

Comment: good one ! such an easy fix for my issue. Thanks @erdekhayser

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot *know* that `collectionView` will always be `collectionView1`
or `collectionView2` in your program and therefore it gives an error message.

What you can do is to add an `else` case to make the compiler happy.
If everything does well, the `else` case will never be executed. If there is a logic
error in your program and both `if` conditions do not match, then (in the
"Debug" configuration) the program will abort with an error message.

```
  if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1)) {
       let cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
       // set cell properties ... 
       return cell
  }
  else if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2)) {
      let cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
      // set cell properties ... 
      return cell
  }
  else {
      assertionFailure("unexpected collectionView")
      return UICollectionViewCell()
  }
```

Alternatively (and this is only a slight variant of the previous two answers),
declare the `cell` as an implicitly unwrapped optional outside the `if` blocks:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell : UICollectionViewCell!
    if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1)){
        cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
        // set cell properties ... 
    } else if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2)){
        cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
        // set cell properties ... 
    }
    return cell
}
```

If none of the conditions match then `nil` is returned which also gives a
runtime exception.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to everyone answering, please not use `var`.
Secondly, of course that is a correct error compiler-wise since the delegate method doesn't ensure that `collectionView` is either one of your defined ones, and requires that you return a valid cell so if you want to keep in the code both cases explicitly then you need to define a valid but never used case too.
Also note that casting your cells to the proper subclass is useless here since they still are instantiated as the right class and still returned as a `UICollectionViewCell` as the delegate method signatures suggests.

Here's a *Swifter* way of doing it:

```
/// define this in any .swift file included in your project
func ~=<T: AnyObject>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs
}
```

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = cellReuseIdentifierForCollectionView(collectionView)
    return epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
}

private func cellReuseIdentifierForCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> String {
    switch collectionView {
    case collectionView1:
        return "Cell1"
    case collectionView2:
        return "Cell2"
    default:
        return "" // this never happens but is still a bit of a code smell
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right that `cell` need not be variable in the code in the question or in my first suggested solution, I have fixed that (thank you!). In my second suggested solution and in the code from the other answers, `cell` needs to be a `var` because the variable is modified later. – Casting to the concrete cell subclass is necessary because most probably  you want to set some cell *properties* in that method.

Comment: Using a switch here is elegant, but it should work without the custom matching operator.

Comment: If you want to set subclass-specific properties there then yes, the cast is necessary. But that is usually done in a subsequently called `configureCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` where you would cast through another `switch` statement.
Also yes, in that second solution you need a `var`, and that's why you don't do it like that :)
Also, without defining the custom `~=`, two `UICollectionViewCell` objects don't fit in any system implementation of it, so they can't be put like that in a `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to return a `UICollectionViewCell`, it would be better if you create a single var for that and return it (I'm not a fan of writing multiple return statement in a method) So you can change it to something like:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
      var cell = UICollectionViewCell()
      if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1))
      {
         cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
      }
      else if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2))
      {
         cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
      }
      return cell
}
```

Comment: I can't do that so I have custom IBOutlets in any kind of cell.

Comment: @Supermafete: What you can't do ? I didn't understand that. The accepted answer suggests the same solution. So what you mean by the above statement ?

Comment: In one case cell has two labels and in the other one has an UIImage. If I descent the cell from UICollectionViewCell I can't access to the outlets. The answer from erdekhayser has the key in the last "else". This way I can make two returns inside the if..else block.

Comment: @Supermafete: You can always configure the cells in the if else, using typecasting. So it's a misleading info you provided. He is also creating cell as a function scope variable and initialized it with UICollectionView. So the information you providing is incorrect. Anyway, if that helped you, then no issues.

Comment: you are right. I didn't want to fill the post with a lot of unuseful code. My mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution! More easy than it seems. Only must replace the "else if" by an "else":

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  if (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView1)) {
     var cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell1
     return cell
  }
  else (collectionView.isEqual(collectionView2)) {
    var cell = self.epgCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell2
    return cell
  }
```

}

It works now. Thank you all guys!